# How do I get rid of GRUB and go back to Windows 10 only

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, grub2, xubuntu

There are answers to similar questions about prior Windows releases (XP and 7 mostly), but I cannot follow them in Windows 10.  Too many menu options and commands do not exist in Windows 10.

My situation: I have a Windows 10 installed on the first 3 partitions of the MBR, with Ubuntu and Fedora in logical partitions.  I boot with GRUB 2.  I also have another disk that is formatted with GPT.  I now wish to change to GPT partitioning on the first drive, because I'm moving to larger disks and want larger partitions.  My goal is to have the Windows loader managing Windows on one drive, and GRUB2 only on the other drive.  I expect I'll have Linux data partitions on both drives, since they'll then both be GPT, and I already do something like this on another machine.

Having lots of the new disks, I've been able to experiment a bit, but basically got nowhere.  I've forgotten details of most attempts, but in the most recent, I made a clone
of my /dev/sda, used gparted to delete all but the first 3 partitions of the clone -- leaving just the Windows partitions, then updated GRUB so it saw the Windows on the new /dev/sdc, and attempted to reboot into it.  Windows would not start, complaining that a required device was not present, then attempted to restart, which never finished.  I was unable to find any details about the "missing device".  This all happened in the original chassis, with the original partitions still intact with the added third drive attached in a drive dock.

I'm willing to take extreme measures, such as installing Windows fresh, but I no longer
seem to have the sticker with the Windows activation code.

Can I make this work somehow?

Comment: You have lots of misconceptions here and a "wrongly" configured multi-boot to start with. The first thing you should learn is how UEFI mode works and its requirements, then keep in mind that Windows 10 should always be installed in UEFI mode in any UEFI based computer -and- Windows strictly requires GPT for UEFI mode. Also ALL OSes should be installed in UEFI mode. And indeed obsolete instructions from the BIOS era aren't applicable, And you're making harder than it should be. ONLY ONE ESP per system is required and all bootloaders should go there irrespective of where the OSes are installed

Comment: Thanks @ ChanganAuto ; I kind of knew I was off-base.  Some of what you stated I already knew.  It has MBR booting because it is a Dell Optiplex 990 -- which was produced when EFI was quite rare, and Windows did not understand GPT.  What I had may seem wrong, but it was all one could do when I started this.   Only one ESP is fine with me -- I wasn't planning on deviating from that.  But the part I don't yet understand is now Linux and GRUB are going to co-exist with whatever Windows does.  I want to be able to remove Linux without disturbing Windows.  It's an issue with what I have.

Comment: To clarify: this question is about how to make the Windows that was on MBR booted by GRUB2 into a Windows on GPT and EFI without GRUB2 at all.  I can add the rest later.

Comment: The best option is to unplug any drive you are not using for the installation then go into BIOS setup Safe Boot etc, then install windows with GPT and finally install Ubuntu

Comment: The goal of this question is to avoid a new install, preserving my configuration and data in the old one.  I wanted to use MBR2GPT but could not get it to work.